# Can You Make A Certain Instantiated Clone Of A Prefab In Unity Get Destroyed When Something Enters Its Trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I have a bullet that gets shot from a gun on your player when you left-click. I can't specifically destroy the bullet that hits something, it destroys all of the bullets.  :C
I Assume A Good Fix For This Would Be To Make It Destroy Itself When Something Enters Its Trigger?
I Don't Know How To Do That Though So If Anyone Can Help That Would Be Awesome!
If You Want To See My Code Then You Can Just Ask.

this is on the thing that the bullet hits:

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    enemyHealth -= 2f;
    ishit = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit()
{
    ishit = false;
}
```

its setting a static variable to true and false.
this is on the bullet:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * mspeed * Time.deltaTime);
    bool hit = Enemy.ishit;
    if (hit == true)
    {
        Object.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

its using the static bool to destroy itself

Thanks!

Comment: Normally, on stackoverflow, you provide [a minimal example of what you already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the code you posted. If this fixes your problem, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Is that C# or UnityScript?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is calling [`Object.Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) on your bullet instance.
That will not destroy any other bullet.

If you mean to destroy the object associated with the current script, you can also call `Object.Destroy` on `this.gameObject`.

You can do this call [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

Edit: Your problem is not that `Object.Destroy` is destroying all bullets, but rather that every bullet destroys itself when one bullet hits.
You might want to try:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider bullet)
{
    enemyHealth -= 2f;
    Object.Destroy(bullet.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: I still can't make it work. once a bullet hits something you can't shoot. Also, it still destroys every current bullet that is copied from that one Prefab

Comment: Did you get a chance to look over the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guideline? We probably won't be able to do much better than the pointers above, without you providing one of those.

Comment: this is the Enemy Code (The Thing The Bullet Is Hitting)

Comment: i can't post it XD

Comment: It's in the question now!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script on "damageable" objects tracking collision and destroying the bullet that colides with it, or have the script on the bullet prefab destroying it self on collision.

Deppending on your game an alternative approach is to not instantiate bullets at all, if you are shooting bullets that move as fast as bullets really move, the player isnt going to see them anyway, you can use raycast to see if you are hitting something when the player shoots, make a sound, a muzzle flash, drop an empty cartdrige on the ground, and in case the player hits anything, instantiate some particles or whatever effect the bullet would have on the other end and be done with it...

Comment: how to you do that?

Comment: Looks like you are on one of your first projects in unity, you got some reading to do, i also learned a lot from videos search the web, the next two links are about raycasting, but you should brobably learn hot to attach scripts to prefabs and instantiating/destroying them: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EINgIoTG8D4